# RabbitMQ (OSX) : ERROR: epmd error for host x1-6-20-0c-c8-19-6b-bd: timeout (timed out)

Tags: macos, rabbitmq

I'm working on OSX 10.10.5 and installed RabbitMQ using the tarball.

Running it via the script :

```
bash sbin/rabbitmq-server
```

The first time it ran, but after a restart, it is giving out this error :

```
ERROR: epmd error for host x1-6-20-0c-c8-19-6b-bd: timeout (timed out)
```

`sbin/rabbitmqctl status` returns this :

```
Status of node 'rabbit@x1-6-20-0c-c8-19-6b-bd' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@x1-6-20-0c-c8-19-6b-bd': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@x1-6-20-0c-c8-19-6b-bd']

rabbit@x1-6-20-0c-c8-19-6b-bd:
  * unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on x1-6-20-0c-c8-19-6b-bd: timeout (timed out)


current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-25@x1-6-20-0c-c8-19-6b-bd'
- home dir: /Users/mohit
- cookie hash: FOxL2w3eJGpNkenIS5ebSw==
```

Please help me resolve this, thanks!

Update : Interestingly it works when i switch back to my personal network from the office network. Possibly something to do with port / network firewall?

Answer (score 2):

Add a configuration file:

```
/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
```

Add a line as below:

```
NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
```